# JQuery Toggle Method Slow on 1000+ UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui

I am working on a project where I am building a treeview and in some cases my tree could have a 1000+ child nodes.  The problem is its really slow on like a IE7 machine.

I'm not doing any kind of animation or anything, just simply trying to hide the next UL in the item using JQuery's toggle feature.  Does anyone have any ideas of how to improve the performance?

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you provide some sample code. Not all 1,000, but the basic ul structure you are working with.

Comment: its just your typical ul li a structure with nest ul's in the li's

Answer (score 2):

If toggle is slow, you can set css styles directly via jquery like:

```
$(".tree_item").click(function(){
  //check the next ul if it is expanded or not
  if(this.next('ul:hidden').length == 0){
    //if expanded hide it
    this.next('ul').css('display', 'none');
  }else{
    //if not shown, show it
    this.next('ul').css('display', 'block');
  }
});
```

such approach would help. I don't know if it would work faster but give it a try...

Sinan.

Comment: I had the same problem, rewrite it with my own css setters and it was much, much faster!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build at start your own tree object from DOM document.

Just iterate through all elements and nest them in standard attributes and variables. You can make additional parent and children pointers using  `$(element).get(0).parent = $(parent).get(0);`

Then if you want to get specified elements use `$.map` function.

We used it to prepare something like firebug on a project. It rebuilded all 5000+ nodes portal in 3 sec and provided fast access on ie6+

Comment: Ok so believe it or not its actually quite a bit faster to spin through all those child LI's and set a display:none than just do it once to the parent UL.  Sometimes i hate JS, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not surprised at all that this is slow if your treeview is that big. Silverlight 3 handles this problem with [UI Virtualization](http://www.kirupa.com/net/ui_virtualization_pg1.htm).

You'll have to roll your own in javascript, but it shouldn't be that hard. Just make a huge blank div that's the size of what the rendered tree would have been, and put it inside a scrollable div, and then only render what should show up. Change it on the onscroll event.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that .toggle(showOrHide) is fast. It was added in jQuery 1.3 and really makes a difference on large collections (50+ elements) in IE8 if animation is not required. The current visibility state can be obtained from the first element, e.g.:

```
    var isVisible = $('.myClass').first().is(':visible');
    $('.myClass').toggle(!isVisible);
```